# In a torsion module over a PID, is the annihilator of a sum of two elements the product of the annihilators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a PID, and $M$ a torsion $R$-module. Let $m,m'\in M$ such that $\mathrm{ann}(m)=(c)$ and $\mathrm{ann}(m')=(c')$ with $c$ and $c'$ coprimes. Is true that $\mathrm{ann}(m+m')=(cc')$?
If that's the case, how can I show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction is easy : if $d \in (cc')$, write $d = acc'$ so that $d(m+m') = ac'(cm) + ac(c'm') = 0+0=0$.

Conversely, assume $d(m+m') = 0$. Then $dm = -dm'$ and $0 = d(cm) = cdm = -dcm'$, hence $-dc \in \mathrm{Ann}_R(m')$, which means $c'$ divides $-dc$. But $c'$ and $c$ are coprime, hence $c'$ divides $d$. Similarly $c$ divides $d$, hence since $c$ and $c'$ are coprime, $cc'$ divides $d$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: @user : Thank you for the comment, but I wanted to add that the reward system on this website is all about reputation ; when you think someone has a good answer or a good question, you upvote it ; when you ask a question and someone gives the best answer to your question in your opinion, you approve it by clicking the check right below the downvote button on this answer. :)